# Uncaught Reference Error: function StartOver() is not defined at HTMLButtonElement.onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, bootbox

I have using an Iframe from third party in my razor view page for payment processing,  and I want to implement Start Over and Finish Up button using javascript at the bottom section of the page. The script tag to submit init form need to be as it is otherwise the Iframe will not load . All the necessary libraries are included in layout page.

View page Code -

```
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Payment Page";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
@model MyModel
<p></p>

<div class="row ">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="panel panel-primary panel-title">
            <div class="panel-heading text-bold">Embedded UI Component</div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <iframe name="client" style="width:100%;height:600px;position:center;left:0;top:0;border:thick"></iframe>
                <form action="@Model.IframeUrl" id="initForm" target="client" method="POST" style="display:none">
                    <input name="X-BEARER-TOKEN" value="@Model.AgentAccessToken">
                    <input name="X-REFRESH-TOKEN" value="@Model.AgentRefreshToken">
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
<div class="row ">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="panel panel-primary panel-title">
            <div class="panel-heading text-bold">Payment Section Bottom</div>
            <div class="panel-body" style="width:100%;height:150px;position:center;left:0;top:0;border:thick">
                <h6 style="font-style:italic;color:red">[Populate here.]</h6>

                @Html.Hidden("sessionGuid", "@Model.SessionGuid.ToString()")
                <form>
                    <button id="start" class="btn btn-info" onclick="StartOver()">Start Over</button>
                    <button id="finish" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="FinishUp()">Finish Up</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
<script>
    document.getElementById("initForm").submit();
</script>

<script>
    debugger;
    function StartOver() {

        //e.preventDefault();

       /* if (confirm("Are you sure you want to start over the Payment Process?")) {
            console.log("pressed yes");
        }

        else {
            console.log("pressed no");
        }*/
        bootbox.confirm({
               
                
                message: "Are you sure you want to start over the Payment Process?",
                buttons: {
                    confirm: {
                        label: 'Yes',
                        className: 'btn-success'
                    },
                    cancel: {
                        label: 'No',
                        className: 'btn-danger'
                    }
                },
                callback: function (result) {
                    var email  = @Model.Email;
                    debugger;
                    if (result)
                    {
                        if (result) {
                        var request = $.ajax({
                            url: 'MyController/StartOverSession',
                            type: 'GET',
                            data: { Email = email },
                            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
                        });
                    }
                    }
                }
        });
    }

    function FinishUp() {
        bootbox.confirm({
            message: "Are you sure you want to finish the Payment Process?",
            buttons: {
                confirm: {
                    label: 'Yes',
                    className: 'btn-success'
                },
                cancel: {
                    label: 'No',
                    className: 'btn-danger'
                }
            },
            callback: function (result) {
                if (result) {
                    window.location.href = "/Thankyou.cshtml";
                    }
            }
        });
    }

</script>
```

When I click on Start Over button, I get "StartOver() is not defined at HTMLButtonElement.onclick ". The scripts tags are within  tags of HTML.  I have checked other related question for this error, but they are not helpful as most of them are either syntax error or  jsfiddle settings related. The confirm() method in the comments works.

Answer (score 0):

The default `type` value for a `<button>` element is "submit", so your "Start Over" button is triggering a form submission.

The JavaScript confirm() function will generate a dialog which will block the page (and therefore the form submission) processing until it has been dismissed. Bootbox's functions can't do that - all it's really doing is generating a Bootstrap modal on the fly. Bootstrap modals are just positioned `<div>` elements, so there's no page blocking (nor can there be). We do cover this in the [Known Limitations](http://bootboxjs.com/documentation.html#known-limitations) section of the documentation.

Two options, based on your code:

1. Set the type attribute on both buttons to "button".

```html
<form>
    <button type="button" id="start" class="btn btn-info" onclick="StartOver()">Start Over</button>
    <button type="button" id="finish" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="FinishUp()">Finish Up</button>
</form>
```

2. Use the preventDefault() function you've currently commented out in your code. You just need to add `e` as an parameter for that to work.

```js
debugger;
function StartOver(e) {
    // prevent the button's default action (submit, in this case)
    e.preventDefault();

    bootbox.confirm({
        message: "Are you sure you want to start over the Payment Process?",
        buttons: {
            confirm: {
                label: 'Yes',
                className: 'btn-success'
            },
            cancel: {
                label: 'No',
                className: 'btn-danger'
            }
        },
        callback: function (result) {
            var email  = '@Model.Email';
            debugger;
            if (result) {
                var request = $.ajax({
                    url: 'MyController/StartOverSession',
                    type: 'GET',
                    data: { Email = email },
                    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
                })
                .done(function(response, status, jqxhr){
                    
                    // do something when a successful (status code 200) response is received
                    
                })
                .fail(function(jqxhr, status, error){
                    
                    // do something when an error (status code  other than 200, including 30x redirects) response is received
                    
                });
            }
        }
    });
}
```